# FormGroup instance needed for formGroup error

Tags: angular, formgroups

I get "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance" error. What is my mistake? I will get coinamount and sellcost information via formgrup and make an object. Then send the object to a function.

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="addArchivedOperationForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          formControlName="coinamount"
          type="number"
          class="form-control bg-dark"
          id="floatingInput2"
          placeholder="Satış Adedi:"
        />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          formControlName="sellcost"
          type="number"
          class="form-control bg-dark"
          id="floatingInput3"
          placeholder="Satış Fiyatı:"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
```

component.ts:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

addArchivedOperationForm: FormGroup;


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createArchivedOperationForm()
 }

createArchivedOperationForm() {
    this.addCoinForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userid:0,
      buycost:0,
      coinsymbol:'',
      coinamount: ['', Validators.required],
      sellcost: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above situation is caused due to this incorrect line of code:

```
<form [formGroup]="addArchivedOperationForm">
```

The name of the property containing the FormGroup is addCoinForm as declared in your .ts code.
So, make this change in your html file and verify:

```
<form [formGroup]="addCoinForm">
```

instead of <form [formGroup]="addArchivedOperationForm"> and initialize addCoinForm as

```
addCoinForm: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the example you provided you are initializing `addCoinForm` in the `ngOnInit()` function but you are using `addArchivedOperationForm` in the DOM.

You should always initialize the `FormGroup` before passing it to the DOM, either in the constructor or during the component initialization.

Try to substitute `this.addCoinForm` with `this.addArchivedOperationForm` in the `ngOnInit()` or provide a initializer for that form group.